# knn, cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

```
y = df.pitch_name
y = np.array(y)
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder()
y = ord_enc.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=12345
)
knn_model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=3)
knn_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn_model.predict([X_test[0]])
```

X has all float value and y is all string type. if I use ordinalEncoder and predict with the model, it works but the issue is that the result I am getting is sometime not a whole number (e.g. 6.3333) when I want to get the exact category.

So whenever I fit the model with the raw categorical value, string, I see this error message **TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type**. When I check error message, I suppose that the error is happening due to the 238 where they try to get y_pred = np.mean(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1) when it should be median since y is a list of string? any help will be appreciated.

```
    237         if weights is None:
--> 238             y_pred = np.mean(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1)
    239         else:
    240             y_pred = np.empty((X.shape[0], _y.shape[1]), dtype=np.float64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I misunderstood something, but it sounds like you are trying to perform classification with a regression model: `KNeighborsRegressor`.

From [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors-regression) you can see that:

> Neighbors-based regression can be used in cases where the data labels are continuous rather than discrete variables. The label assigned to a query point is computed based on the **mean of the labels of its nearest neighbors**.

So, by using the `OrdinalEncoder`, you just encoded the float categories, however, afterwards you predicted the mean of the labels of its nearest neighbors, which will not be an integer, and thus not a category.

I suggest that you read [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbors-classification), to learn how to use a `KNeighborsClassifier`.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I really did use "KNeighborsRegressor" instead of the classifier. I struggle for a good 1 hour and you saved my life. Thank you Nikolas